# Simple supply and demand problem

Tags: supply-and-demand, equilibrium

I'm not sure about this, can I ask you if I'm wrong? Thanks.

**Data:**
$$Q_{s}=P/2$$
$$Q_{d}=P-42$$

**Questions:**

*a) How many units will be traded at 35 dollars? At $14 dollars?*

*b) What quantity at what price will be in equilibrium?*

*c) What is the total revenue from sales?*

**Answer a**

$$Q_{s}=P/2 => P=2Q_{s}$$
$$Q_{d}=P-42 => P=Q_{d}+42$$
$$P/2=P-42$$
$$P_{eq}=84$$

35 dollars is below 84 dollars, therefore, there is a shortage (we should plug the 35 dollars into the supply equation)

=> 17 units will be sold at that price (am I correct to round down?)

$$Q_{s}=35/2 = 17.5$$

14 dollars also is below 84 dollars, therefore, there is a shortage too (we should plug the 14 dollars into the supply equation)

=> 7 units will be sold at that price

$$Q_{s}=14/2 = 7$$

**Answer b**

$$P_{eq}=84$$
$$Q_{eq}=P_{eq} /2 = P_{eq}-42$$
$$Q_{eq}= 42$$

**Answer c**

The total revenue would be, respectively:
$$84*42 = 3528$$
$$35*17 = 595$$
$$14*7 = 98$$

I know it's supposed to be simple but not sure if I'm rounding correctly (17.5 to 17) and if those dramatic drops in revenue are to be expected.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your demand function, it should be decreasing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure I follow you. A demand function is always decreasing. Do you mean by that that I'm incorrect somewhere? I would like more assurance, not less so I would be grateful if you can be more specific.
1) I'm not sure if I should use 17 instead of 17.5. Is 17 correct?
2) I only used the supply function to plug my variables as there is a shortage not a surplus. Therefore I never used the demand function here. Am I wrong then?
Thanks.

Comment: Your demand is $Q_d=P-42$, which is increasing in price. I guess it should be $42-P$. Then your calculations will change accordingly. And in general you shouldn't round to integers (if not instructed to do so) since units could well be divisible.

Comment: Ok, I got it ! super thanks.
Strange because the original data is part of the question. So this would mean there is an issue there.